# React cannot load image from url, but can load with normal http call

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cdn

Hello I tried to load a manga image from this URL for example (mangaeden api)

```
<img src="https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/0d/0d02206d3b612b859a386537d7de8d7941427c696e9b16a99d3891a0.jpg" />
```

this is returning 403 on the network log history. [failed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpZXo.png)

But when I tried to get the image from browser, it is showing just fine
[success image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zr9a.png)

current web state [my project current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jugsK.png)

the same image directly called from browser [success image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNZpO.jpg)

my react code

```
            {
              mangaList.manga.map(manga_object => (
                <div className="col-sm-3" key={manga_object.i}>
                  <div className="card">
                    <img
                      className="card-img-top"
                      alt={manga_object.t}
                      rcset={
                        "https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/600x/" + manga_object.im + " 600w," +
                        "https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/" + manga_object.im + " 975w"
                      }
                      src={"https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/" + manga_object.im}
                    />
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <p className="card-text">{manga_object.t}</p>
                      <a href={"https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/" + manga_object.im} target="_blank">link</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            }
```

Comment: What is 'rcset'? Can you try without it?

Comment: that's the img properties from manga eden, i tried to copy the way they load the image. also not working after i removed it. getting thos properties from here https://www.mangaeden.com/en/en-manga/bleach/686/1/

Comment: Are you sure that 'mangaList.manga' is an array and contains any information?

Comment: yes it is, i will attach how the site behaves currently

Comment: I just saw the way it behaves and it seems like you need to use something else to fetch the image because you are getting the 403 status code which means the resource is not letting your img tag to get the file you want.

Comment: will try that one

Comment: that's work like magic @Hangindev thanks for pointing that out